# How can I update only certain fields in a Django model form?

Tags: python, django

I have a model form that I use to update a model.

```
class Turtle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class TurtleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Turtle
```

Sometimes I don't need to update the entire model, but only want to update one of the fields.  So when I POST the form only has information for the description.  When I do that the model never saves because it thinks that the name is being blanked out while my intent is that the name not change and just be used from the model.

```
    turtle_form = TurtleForm(request.POST, instance=object)
    if turtle_form.is_valid():
        turtle_form.save()
```

Is there any way to make this happen?  Thanks!

Comment: What if you want the field to display still so you want the whole form, each field is part of a loop with a submit button that appears next to the form input field - but if you submit only one change then it wants to update the whole form and leave everything else empty (I have not even gotten it to save the particular field yet, just blanks everything from the db row that fills the fields of that particular form out)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only use specified fields:

```
class FirstModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TheModel
        fields = ('title',)
    def clean_title(self....
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#controlling-which-fields-are-used-with-fields-and-exclude

It is common to use different ModelForms for a model in different views, when you need different features. So creating another form for the model that uses the same behaviour (say `clean_<fieldname>` methods etc.) use:

```
class SecondModelForm(FirstModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TheModel
        fields = ('title', 'description')
```

Comment: Thanks.  The nice thing about this method is that I only need to send out the full form for populating the template and then I can choose different forms depending on what I've posted.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to update a field, remove it from the form via the Meta `exclude` tuple:

```
class Meta:
    exclude = ('title',)
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want to do.  I have a single TurtleForm and at one spot on the page I want to just have the description and at another spot I want to have the full form.  Is this possible or do I need to split it out into two different forms?

Comment: TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): exclude